# Multiple Web Server on Single Public IP

Tags: ip, home-server, reverse-proxy, windows-home-server, subdomain

I got an unused server from my office. Set up my server with windows server 2019 with IIS 10 and running Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare Player 16 and set the network mode to Bridge network.

Say, my windows server IP address running IIS is 192.168.100.188 running Wordpress, and my VMWare IP address is 192.168.100.104 running OwnCloud.

My server running IIS (wordpress) was already routed to a domain (ex. example.com) via no-ip DDNS since home ISP use dynamic IP and I can open it on the internet outside the local network.

My question is, How can I route my VMWare IP address (OwnCloud) to a domain (ex. vm.example.com) or (ex. example.com/vm)

I got it running when I go to the local IP (192.168.100.104) with my local device. But how can I route that private IP to the public IP so I can open it on the internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a reverse proxy and then have it "split up" requests so they pull data from tge appropriate host.

Alternatively, get a VPN that offers a static IP and run it from the second web server.

(You can't do what you are attempting with just DNS and/or NAT unless you have different ports - eg https/443 for one site and http/80 for another, or use non-stanard ports which modify the url. )

Comment: So I have 2 option here: 
1. first, use reverse proxy and map the request to the second web server, and
2. second, use VPN with static IP Service on the second web server so the web server bind to the static IP from VPN and the domain (vm.example.com) mapped to the static IP from VPN

is that right?

Comment: Yes. The above are the most logical options. (There may be other corner-case options but they will be along the same theme - get another IP address routed to your system or use a reverse proxy).  Its just occurred to me you might also be able run one of the sites on an alternative port and NAT and use someone like cloudflare to reverse proxy requests and change the port for one of the sites, for example.

Comment: I see... maybe I'll try using reverse proxy since there are open source options because this project is just for my knowledge and curiosity with "what can I do if I have a server". Anyway, do you know good reverse proxy for windows? Does nginx make a windows version?

Comment: I dont "do" Windows.  I know Apache has "mod_proxy" module for its web server which is ideal for this (Ive used this in mission critical applications) - and I understand this works fine on the Windows version.

Comment: Yeah I think I should migrate to linux, some function I found only supported on linux platform. This is my first ever server project and I really enjoy this process of knowing things. Thanks a lot for your support!